# Purpose of Forward Command Controller

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently stumbled across the `forward_command_controller/ForwardCommandController` ros controller while doing some research online. From the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/forward_command_controller/html/classforward__command__controller_1_1ForwardJointGroupCommandController.html#:%7E:text=%3A%3AForwardJointGroupCommandController-,Forward%20command%20controller%20for%20a%20set%20of%20joints.,for%20an%20effort%2Dcontrolled%20joint.), it seems that it can take multiple joints as input and simply forwards them over to the hardware interface node. But how is that different than what the `position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController` does for positions? Or the `velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController` does for velocities, etc?

It seems like there is some redundancy here, and according to the controller [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control), the above controllers even use the forward command controller behind the scenes. This question applies to both ros1 and ros2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392933/purpose-of-forward-command-controller/) by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2021-12-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer not really:

You can see it in the source code. For `position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController`
https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/noetic-devel/position_controllers/src/joint_position_controller.cpp

```
void forward_command_controller::ForwardCommandController<T>::starting(const ros::Time& time)
{
  // Start controller with current joint position
  command_buffer_.writeFromNonRT(joint_.getPosition());
}
```

For `velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController`:
https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/noetic-devel/velocity_controllers/src/joint_group_velocity_controller.cpp

```
void forward_command_controller::ForwardJointGroupCommandController<T>::starting(const ros::Time& time)
{
  // Start controller with 0.0 velocities
  commands_buffer_.readFromRT()->assign(n_joints_, 0.0);
}
```

They both make use of `Forward Command Controller` class but not doing exactly same function.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1